# Replacing divs that can be replaced in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i'm trying to replace some divs with other divs, this works fine but when i try to replace the second load of divs they don't change anymore.

Basicaly I'm trying to create a "winetour" that lets a user choose some options and generates the perfect wine to go along with it.

You get presented with a couple of options (img links) and if you click one the div's content changes and presents another set of clickable images taking you deeper in your process of choosing a great wine.

HTML:

```
<div id"Gelegenheid"> 
    <a href="#" class="hvr-grow" onClick = "continueTour(1)"><img src="Images/Ontbijt.jpg" id="ontbijt" alt="Ontbijt"></a>
    <a href="#" class="hvr-grow" onClick = "continueTour(2)"><img src="Images/Borrel.jpg" id="borrel" alt="Borrel"></a>
    <a href="#" class="hvr-grow" onClick = "continueTour(3)"><img src="Images/Dinner.jpg" id="feest" alt="Diner"></a>
    <a href="#" class="hvr-grow" onClick = "continueTour(4)"><img src="Images/Feest.jpg" id="diner" alt="Feest"></a> 
</div>
<div id"Ontbijt" style="display: none"> Some content that shows trough the "tour"</div>
<div id"Borrel" style="display: none"> Some content that shows trough the "tour"</div>
<div id"Dinner" style="display: none"> 
    <a href="#" class="hvr-grow" onClick = "continueTour(5)"><img src="Images/White.jpeg" id="ontbijt-licht" alt="ontbijt-licht"></a>
</div>
<div id"Dinner-detail-voor" style="display: none"> Some content that shows trough the "tour"</div>
<div id"Dinner-detail-head" style="display: none"> Some content that shows trough the "tour"</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function continueTour(i) {
if (i==1) {
    document.getElementById("Gelegenheid").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Ontbijt").innerHTML;
} else if (i==2) {
    document.getElementById("Gelegenheid").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Borrel").innerHTML;
} else if (i==3) {
    document.getElementById("Gelegenheid").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Diner").innerHTML;
} else if (i==4) {
    document.getElementById("Gelegenheid").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Feest").innerHTML;
} else {
    document.getElementById("Dinner").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Dinner-detail-voor").innerHTML;
}
}
```

So basically if you click on a link that's inside the "Gelegenheid" div you will be taken to for example Dinner, but the problem is, inside dinner there are some more links and i want to link them for example to "Dinner-detail-voor"

I want to make this working with core JavaScript (so no JQuery) but i don't know what's going on?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your replacement no longer has `onClick`.

Comment: at line 7-9 you are missing = in style

Comment: the correct syntax is style="your:code;"

Comment: The onCLick is there?
and the syntax for style is an error, sorry, fixed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.

Added

```
document.getElementById("from").style.display = "none" ;
document.getElementById("to").style.display = "table" ;
```

to each of the javscript index functions, now it works where 'from' is the father and 'to' is the child that is being linked to, not very neat but it works,

If someone has a shorter or alternative solution feel free to post!

Answer (score 0):

first we create an array for all the content, array is base 0 so we start from function myFunction(0); next we create a tag with updated variable in them. the if statement is use to reset the variable when hit max. hope this help.

http://jsfiddle.net/xgay3f83/3/

```
function continueTour(i) {
var content = ['content 1', 'content 2', 'content 3', 'content 4'];
var target = document.getElementById('target');
var next = i + 1;
var end = content.length;

if(next>end) {
    i = 0;
    next = 1;
}

var openTag = '<a href="#" class="hvr-grow" onClick = "continueTour('+next+')">'; 
var closeTag = '</a>';

target.innerHTML = openTag+content[i]+closeTag;    
 }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your input but this isn't exactly what i was looking for.
I believe this sort of scrolls trough the content in ascending order but i'm looking for a branched tour, so for example you pick dinner the user get's pressented with 3 other choices exclusively for dinner that defines the choice further.